# Set content of particular Pivot Item

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I wrote a **Windows Phone 8.1 (WINPRT) App.**
It contains **Pivot**, in which **pivot items are generated dynamically** according to JSON.

For example, when I open Clothing Category Page,>> Summer Wear,Winter Wear etc pivot items are generated dynamically.

Now I am clicking the button to load more items in GridView (ObservableCollection) and it is shown on currently selected PivotItem.

```
(MainPagePivot.SelectedItem as PivotItem).Content = StatusGridObject;
```

How to add these items to some other pivot item and not the selected one.
example i am on pivotitem  having index 0, how to add data to pivot item having  index 4? Any linq query?? I dont want to use *MainPagePivot.SelectedItem* but some other pivot item

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do something like this:

```
((PivotItem)MainPagePivot.Items[index]).Content = StatusGridObject;
```

Of course, thanks to linq you can also use something like .Where() or .Any() on MainPagePivot.Items

example with linq:

```
((PivotItem)MainPagePivot.Items.First(p => p.Name == "PivotItemFour")).Content = StatusGridObject;
```

Let me know if it works!